# Pass jsx as value in an object

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass jsx as a value for a key in an object. This is what I'm doing:

```
const getRightDiv = () => {
    return (
        <div>This is what I want to pass</div>
    );
}

var card = {
    title: "haha",
    subtitle: "yes",
    div: getRightDiv()
}

//In my Child Component
return (
    <div>
        { card.title === "haha" && card.div}
    </div>
);
```

But this isn't working. There is no error message, but the div doesn't render. How can I pass jsx in an object?

Comment: `card.title === "haha" && props.card.div` why are you using props in the second part?

Comment: My bad, it should be card.div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not passing `props` correctly to your child component.
I hope it will help you

```
 const getRightDiv = () => {
  return <div>This is what I want to pass </div>;
};
var card = {
  title: "haha",
  subtitle: "yes",
  div: getRightDiv(),
};
//In my Child Component
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return <div>{card.title === "haha" && props.card.div}</div>;
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return <ChildComponent card={card} />;
};
export default ParentComponent;
```

Comment: if the component is receiving the card as a prop you probably want to check `props.card.title==="haha"` instead of `card.title`

Answer (score -1):

I think it'll work

```
const GetRightDiv = () => {
    return (
        <div>This is what I want to pass</div>
    );
}

var card = {
    title: "haha",
    subtitle: "yes",
    div: <GetRightDiv/>
}

//In my Child Component
return (
    <div>
        { card.title === "haha" && props.card.div}
    </div>
);
```

you can pass props to `GetRightDiv` too if you want to.